# How to set specific height for text in golang? (SDL2 TTF)

Tags: go, size, sdl-2, truetype

So, I finally understood how to set text to screen using SDL2 ttf, but I also discovered, that text covers the entire screen, while I need text to be smaller, but I haven't found anything here https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/ttf
Is there a way to make text smaller?

Here's my code:

```golang
func WriteChoices() {
    font, _ := ttf.OpenFont("arial.ttf", 1920)
    font.SetOutline(21)
    surface, _ := font.RenderUTF8Solid("Player Computer", sdl.Color{0, 0, 50, 255})
    texture, _ := renderer.CreateTextureFromSurface(surface)
    
    renderer.Copy(texture, nil, nil)
    font.Close()
    surface.Free()
    texture.Destroy()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can just reduce font size by loading the font like so.

```
func WriteChoices() {
    font, _ := ttf.OpenFont("arial.ttf", 20)
    font.SetOutline(21)
    surface, _ := font.RenderUTF8Solid("Player Computer", sdl.Color{0, 0, 50, 255})
    texture, _ := renderer.CreateTextureFromSurface(surface)
    renderer.Copy(texture, nil, sdl.{W:surface.W,H:surface.H})
    font.Close()
    surface.Free()
    texture.Destroy()
}
```

This may work but i cant test right now, Sorry if i just wasted your time

Comment: No, by doing that quality of text decreases